# Unity не видит базу данных SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity3d

При билде приложения Unity не загружает информацию из базы,однако при запуске приложения внутри самого движка все работает отлично,каким образом можно решить проблему?

Comment: Можете использовать мое готовое решение:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000936/236729

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, ваши проблемы связаны с тем, что сам файл базы данных находится не в подходящей для этого директории Unity проекта. Подобные проблемы также могут возникать не только с базой данных, но и с другими файлами (например .json) файлами. Например, при использовании директории Streaming Assets, json файлы прекрасно читаются в самой Unity и Standalone сборках, но не работают на Andoid. Посмотрите информацию [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705925/how-to-connect-a-sqlite-db-in-unity-3d-5no-plugins) и [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181239/).